# How to display current daytime in html form .net

Tags: c#, html, .net

I have an html form that includes Time Created field, and i want to display current date and time in the form when loaded. Ive tried many .ToString() overloads and time formats and nothing seems to display the value.

```
<label asp-for="TimeCreated" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="TimeCreated" class="form-control" value="@{DateTime.Now.ToString("DD-MM-YYYYThh:mm");}" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="TimeCreated" class="text-danger"></span>
```

Comment: What do you get and what do you expect?

Comment: i expect form "timecreated" be already filled with DateTime.Now when loaded

Comment: And there were no compilation errors or warnings? Try removing the `;` at the end of the function call. Exactly how this could be resolved depends on which version of ASP.NET your are running

Comment: I am running asp.net 5.0
no warnings, no compilation errors, the form is filled with "blank" pre-filled template "DD.MM.YYYY hh.mm"

Comment: Have you tried a static value? If that works there's something wrong with you @ and you need to look at that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DateTime.Today
Here tt refers to AM/PM

```
@DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy tt hh:mm")
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to define `type="datetime-local"` into the input tag.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).